# Adding advice to an autoloaded function

Tags: advice, autoload

I want to add advice to an alias to a function in an internal elisp package at work, gating the logic on a variable.

Both the function and the alias is marked autoload.

Conceptually:

```
;;;###autoload 
(defun something-get ()
  ....)

;;;###autoload 
(defalias 'something 'something-get)
```

What I want is:

```
(defvar enable-something-advice-p nil)

(and enable-something-advice-p
     (defadvice something (before fix-something enable)
       ;;; do stuff
       )
```

Questions:

1. How do I make sure the advice takes effect?    Just mark autoload?
2. How do I make the advice conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to put a conditional form around the function:

```
(when (fboundp 'my-function-generating-compilation-errors)
   ....)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't make the advice conditional, but only its effect:

```
(defadvice something (before fix-something enable)
  (when enable-something-advice-p
    ;;; do stuff
    ))
```

Tho of course I'd use `advice-add` instead:

```
(advice-add 'something :before
  (lambda ()
    (when enable-something-advice-p
      ;;; do stuff
      )))
```

Pieces of advice can be installed before the function is defined (they even survive the function's redefinition), so the fact that the function is autoloaded is not a problem at all.

Comment: Does the (defadvice) or (advise-add) need to be marked `;;;autoload' to be made generally available?

Comment: No, unless you want that advice to be enabled before the file in which it's located is loaded (this would be very unusual).

Comment: I still don't understand.

(something) is autoloaded.  If this is called before a call to require(), is the advice attached?

Comment: @Realraptor: Advising as-yet-undefined functions is known as "forward advice", and it basically Just Works (i.e. *you* don't need to care whether or not the target function is defined).  When a function gets defined, any forward advice for it will be activated.  See also the commentary in `advice.el` under the heading "Forward advice, automatic advice activation".

Comment: ...and an autoload definition is still just an autoload definition -- "advising an autoload definition" isn't a problem you need to worry about.  When the autoload is triggered and the real function is defined, that's when the forward advice is processed.